# VBA: How to create a series in a chart with more than 1 X value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a new series with VBA that will have more than 1 X-value.

It's no problem when creating a series with only 1 X-value but it doesn't work with more than that. Can anyone help?

Works:

```
.XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

Doesn't work (run time error 1004):

```
.XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 14) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 15) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 16) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 17) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 18) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 19) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 20) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 21) & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 22).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addresses for the `XValues` need to be comma separated.

The result should look something like: `=[Map1]Sheet1!C1,[Map1]Sheet1!N1:V1`

---

So you need to connect two addresses with `& "," &`.

```
.XValues = "=" & dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) & "," & _
   dataws.Range(dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 14), dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 22)).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

Note that continuous cells can be combined to one range address like:

```
dataws.Range(dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 14), dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 22))
```

which means cell 14 up to cell 22. So you don't need to add them separately.